# .htaccess not working on Windows

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got Apache 2.2 installed on my Windows machine, and there seems to be a problem with .htaccess.

I enabled `mod_rewrite` in `httpd.conf` file, and wrote some conditions into my .htaccess, but nothing works. I tried putting some garbage into it, to see if it would return Internal Server Error, but not even that would work. What could be the problem?

Could the problem be, that my Apache is located in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation", and my server root is at "C:\Users\Grega\Server"? I can't find anything that would point to .htaccess in httpd.conf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `AllowOverride None` set for the directory `C:\Users\Grega\Server`. Otherwise htaccess files could be entirely ignored. You could turn all the overrides on by an `AllowOverride All` or at the very least `AllowOverride FileInfo`.

Comment: This helps.  Also don't forget to enable your LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf

Comment: worked perfectly. On my mac, the same code `AllowOverride None` worked without any trouble though. Had to change it for windows.

Comment: # Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /sc19/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

Answer (score -2):

> Make sure you don't have AllowOverride None set for the directory C:\Users\Grega\Server. Otherwise htaccess files could be entirely ignored. You could turn all the overrides on by an AllowOverride All or at the very least AllowOverride FileInfo.
>
> Jon Lin

For me this didn't work. But i found a solution. Go to \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf and find

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex first_page.html if_not_found.html
</IfModule>`
```

Change `first_page.html` to anything you want.

(I'm not native english speaker, so I apologize for my bad english.)

Comment: your english is fine. If you can explain something technical to a native speaker, and they get it, then you've arrived